# Can I publish my project to npm, not as a package but a whole project including folders and files?

Tags: npm, publish, init

Can I publish my project to npm, not as a package but a whole project (folder and file)? So I can init it again using command like "npm init my-project".

Maybe it is like a git clone but my boss want it using npm. Can I do that?

So all the structure is included when I init it, like folder and files.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible. An alternative would be to publish a package which inits the project for you, so you can do something like `npx my-project-init`

Comment: @awarrier99 ok thank you, i am publishing it as package then copy all the file & folder to the root using postinstall script